# UIToolBar Not Showing In 3.5 Inch Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, uitoolbar

I have an iPhone app that has a UIToolBar added at the bottom in a View Controller with button on it. I was just testing it and found that the UIToolBar is not showing in the 3.5-inch iPhone simulator in Xcode. While its properly showing up in 4-inch iPhone Simulator and 4-inch 64-bit iPhone Simulator. Its even showing up properly on all iPads simulator.

[image: UIToolBar Not Showing]

I don't have any 3.5 inch iPhone to test it on the device since i only own an iPhone 5 and iPad 2. Although its hard to tell but can anyone point out what could be the problem or how can i troubleshoot it to find the problem?

Comment: Do you use autolayout? and if not could you check how the springs and strus are set? for each view

Comment: @elio.d yes i am using auto layout

Comment: Try clicking on the toolbar in storyboard and the from the icons on the bottom left section from second from right select reset to suggested layouts and see if that will solve your issue.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey it worked. Kindly put it as an answer so i can mark it. Thanks!

Comment: @AJ112, I did and I'm glad I was aw to help. Also I gave you an answer on iad question and you never checked my answer as the correct one if my answer was correct and helpful. I would appreciate if you let me know about that question also.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey i will work on the iAd issue later and will update the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try clicking on the toolbar in storyboard and the from the icons on the bottom left section from second from right select reset to suggested layouts and see if that will solve your issue.